# A More Efficient Way to Parse a String in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code that reads a file and creates Regex groups.  Then I walk through the groups and use other matches on keywords to extract what I need. I need the stuff between each keyword and the next space or newline. I am wondering if there is a way using the Regex keyword match itself to discard  what I don't want (the keyword).

```
//create the pattern for the regex
        String VSANMatchString = @"vsan\s(?<number>\d+)[:\s](?<info>.+)\n(\s+name:(?<name>.+)\s+state:(?<state>.+)\s+\n\s+interoperability mode:(?<mode>.+)\s\n\s+loadbalancing:(?<loadbal>.+)\s\n\s+operational state:(?<opstate>.+)\s\n)?";

        //set up the patch
        MatchCollection VSANInfoList = Regex.Matches(block, VSANMatchString);

    // set up the keyword matches
    Regex VSANNum = new Regex(@" \d* ");
Regex VSANName = new Regex(@"name:\S*");
Regex VSANState = new Regex(@"operational state\S*");


        //now we can extract what we need since we know all the VSAN info will be matched to the correct VSAN
        //match each keyword (name, state, etc), then split and extract the value

        foreach (Match m in VSANInfoList)
        {    
            string num=String.Empty;
            string name=String.Empty;
            string state=String.Empty;
            string s = m.ToString();

            if (VSANNum.IsMatch(s)) { num=VSANNum.Match(s).ToString().Trim(); }

            if (VSANName.IsMatch(s)) 
            {

                string totrim = VSANName.Match(s).ToString().Trim();
                string[] strsplit = Regex.Split (totrim, "name:");
                name=strsplit[1].Trim();
            }

            if (VSANState.IsMatch(s))
            {
                string totrim = VSANState.Match(s).ToString().Trim();
                string[] strsplit=Regex.Split (totrim, "state:");
                state=strsplit[1].Trim();
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your single regex should be able to gather all you need.  Try this:

```
string name = m.Groups["name"].Value; // Or was it m.Captures["name"].Value?
```

Comment: thanks.  that is what I needed.  I couldn't find an example of what I wanted online and wasn't sure what property I needed to access from looking at the MatchCollection in the debugger.